# Destructuring an object in order to make the all properties none nested / single level

Tags: javascript

I have this object with the following nested properties.

```
{
  _id: {
    agent_info: {
      name: 'Ritu',
      status: 'active',
      avatar: null
    }
  },
  avg_score: 100,
}
```

I am trying to deconstruct it so that it looks like this.

```
    {
          name: 'Ritu',
          status: 'active',
          avatar: null,
          avg_score: 100,
    }
```

I tried using this `const { _id:{...agent_info} } = user;` but the output remains the same and the object is not altered.

Comment: For what it's worth, the term is *"destructuring"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructuring won't alter the object. It might create a new object, but it won't modify the original.

You can't use a single destructuring operation to get the result you want. You can get close, but it takes two steps.

```
const { _id: { agent_info: { ...result } } } = original;
result.avg_score = original.avg_score;
```

Live Example:

```js
const original = {
  _id: {
    agent_info: {
      name: 'Ritu',
      status: 'active',
      avatar: null
    }
  },
  avg_score: 100,
};

const { _id: { agent_info: { ...result } } } = original;
result.avg_score = original.avg_score;
console.log(result);
```

That copies everything from `original._id.agent_info` into a new object referenced by the `result` constant, then adds in `avg_score`.

You could also do it without reusing `original`, by grabbing `avg_score` in the same operation that creates `result`:

```
const { _id: { agent_info: { ...result } }, avg_score } = original;
result.avg_score = avg_score;
```

Live Example:

```js
const original = {
  _id: {
    agent_info: {
      name: 'Ritu',
      status: 'active',
      avatar: null
    }
  },
  avg_score: 100,
};

const { _id: { agent_info: { ...result } }, avg_score } = original;
result.avg_score = avg_score;
console.log(result);
```

...but that leaves an `avg_score` constant lying around (which is harmless, but...).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this object destructuring using something that is called deep property. [image]

```js
const obj = {
  _id: {
    agent_info: {
      name: 'Ritu',
      status: 'active',
      avatar: null
    }
  },
  avg_score: 100,
};

const {_id:{ agent_info:{ ...res }}} = obj;
res["avg_Score"] = obj.avg_score;

console.log(res);
```

Check out the this [link](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-object-destructuring/) for more info